# wordpress mysql - delete all custom post type

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I've got a wordpress/mysql set up using the 'custom post type' which currently holds about 40,000 rows of data in the wp_posts table of the database.   I'm trying to work on an SQL query that will remove all the rows of a certain custom post type in one go but it keeps telling me I've got a syntax error. The code I'm using is below, apologies if it's simple but SQL is alien to me and I'm struggling to find anything in the forums.

```
DELETE FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE  `post_type` =  'prefix-numberplates'
LIMIT 0 , 3000
```

There are ` around wp_posts & post_type but it won't let me style them on here.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The query looks fine. What is your error message? If you are doing this from the command line, did you `use <databasename>` first?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved -

```
DELETE FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE  `post_type` =  'prefix-numberplates'
```

worked - took the bottom section out & it was fine.

Comment: You're not removing the post meta by running this query, you'll leave a lot of junk in your database.

Answer (score 9):

```
global $wpdb;

// delete all posts by post type.
$sql = 'DELETE `posts`, `pm`
    FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` AS `posts` 
    LEFT JOIN `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta` AS `pm` ON `pm`.`post_id` = `posts`.`ID`
    WHERE `posts`.`post_type` = \'prefix-numberplates\'';
$result = $wpdb->query($sql);
```

This will delete from both posts and postmeta table. It left no junk in db.

Answer (score 5):

The following removes from the posts, postmeta and term_relationships table:

```
DELETE p,tr,pm
    FROM wp_posts p
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships tr
        ON (p.ID = tr.object_id)
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm
        ON (p.ID = pm.post_id)
    WHERE p.post_type = 'post_type_name';
```

Just change 'post_type_name' to the cpt you wish to remove.
Also change table name prefixes where appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This way makes sure you get the right table - $wpdb knows best :)

```
// delete CPT posts ##
global $wpdb;

$posts_table = $wpdb->posts;

$query = "
  DELETE FROM {$posts_table}
  WHERE post_type = 'post_type_name' 
";

$wpdb->query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete p,m from wp_posts p left join wp_postmeta m on p.ID = m.post_id where p.post_type = "my_custom_post_type"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the $wpdb class.

```
$query = "
DELETE FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'prefix-numberplates' 
LIMIT 0, 3000
";

$wpdb->query($query);
```